# Remove specific response history in OkHttpCache not working with it.urls().remove() in Android [Not solved]

Tags: android, okhttp

In my Android - Hilt - Retrofit - OkHttp, I successfully implemented caching mechanism and it is working fine.

Scenario:
In my `client.cache.urls()` right now 3 responses are saved. Let's say

```
google.com/v1/ABC
google.com/v1/123
google.com/v1/XYZ
```

My requirement is that - SECOND time - before invoking api call, I want to remove entire history of `google.com/v1/123`

As per [this](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3661) it says to use `remove()`

But after doing this also, still it is giving me cache response:

```
client.cache?.urls().remove()
```

Also, `urls()` will iterate and remove all urls, but I want to do for specific end point.

Please do not suggest for `FORCE_NETWORK` option, I'm aware about that and it is not fitting into my use case. Kindly help me to remove history of particular API call which has cache response.

Comment: Are you using the iterator to find the items to remove? Your expected to call that function in a for loop.

Comment: @JesseWilson Tried both ways, inside iterator or outside of loop. You know internally it'll iterate and remove all URLs. Also after finding I've no option to remove specific item, I've to call same fun then what's the point?